# Typescript Const enum index signature

Tags: typescript

```js
export const enum Outcome {
  primary = 'primary',
  success = 'success',
  failure = 'failure'
}

export const buttonColors: { [key in Outcome]: string } = { primary: '#007aff', success: '#00C260', failure: '#F56B62' };

// example 1
buttonColors[Outcome.primary]; // works

// example 2 - interface doesn't work

interface IProps {
  outcome: Outcome;
}

const first: IProps = { outcome: Outcome.primary };
buttonColors[first.outcome]; // Error: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type '{ primary: string; success: string; failure: string; }' has no index signature.

// example 3 - class - works
class Props {
  // notice this is class
  outcome: Outcome;
}

const second: Props = new Props();
second.outcome = Outcome.primary;
buttonColors[second.outcome]; // works
```

In all the above cases `const enum` is used to access `buttonColors`, but not sure why when the access is via. an interface, it's not working.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: This is weird, if I split `first` definition into `const first = {} as IProps; first.outcome = Outcome.primary;` it works... So it is not about interface, but assignment

Comment: Currently your code works on the typescript playground. Perhaps an issue solves with TypeScript 2.6.